# Serializing ManytoMany field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to get all the tags associated with a submission. It successfully return the list of the tags when I hit the endpoint to get all the submissions but when I hit a particular submission, I get null as the values.

this is my model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,)       

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)


class Submission(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    abstract = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    comment_for_editor = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    completion_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True, related_name='tags')
    section = models.ForeignKey("Section", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

this is my serializer

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['title']

class startSubmissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = SubmissionFilesSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = ['section', 'title', 'abstract', 'comment_for_editor', 'completion_status', 'files','tags', 'id']


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['user']
        
        files = validated_data.pop('files', [])
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags', None)

        submission = Submission.objects.create(
            author=user,
            **validated_data
        )
        
        tags = str(tags['title']).split(', ')
        print(tags)
        for tag_title in tags:
            tag, _ = Tag.objects.get_or_create(title = tag_title)
            submission.tag.add(tag)
        submission.save()
        
        
        if files != []:
            for file in files:
                SubmissionFiles.objects.create(
                    submission = submission,
                    **file
                )

        return submission
```

I get back all of my submissions

[
{
"section": 1,
"title": "New Submission 11",
"abstract": "diqgduigodui",
"comment_for_editor": "hodihcioshiochiohsioc",
"completion_status": false,
"files": [],
"tags": [
{
"title": 'biology"
},
{
"title": "english"
},
{
"title": "math"
},
{
"title": "youtube"
}
],
"id": 12
},
{
"section": 1,
"title": "New Submission 12",
"abstract": "diqgduigodui",
"comment_for_editor": "hodihcioshiochiohsioc",
"completion_status": false,
"files": [],
"tags": [
{
"title": "biology"
},
{
"title": "english"
},
{
"title": "math"
},
{
"title": "youtube"
}
],
"id": 13
}
]

But i get this when i hit submission/13
{
"section": null,
"title": null,
"abstract": null,
"comment_for_editor": null
}

this is my view

```
class SubmissionView(ModelViewSet):

    """
    View your submissions
    Delete one of your submission   
    Update one of your submission
    Read one of your submission
    """

    # queryset = Submission.objects.all()
    serializer_class = startSubmissionSerializer


    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Submission.objects.prefetch_related('tags').filter(author=user)
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Submission.objects.prefetch_related('tags').filter(author=user)
    
    
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return {'user': user}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a ```/<int:pk>``` to your url pattern and actually write this line:
```return Submission.objects.prefetch_related('tags').filter(author=user)```
as 
```return Submission.objects.prefetch_related('tags').filter(author=user, id=self.kwargs["pk"])```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I suggest you use this script at the top of the class `startSubmissionSerializer` instead of passing the authenticated user by context to the serializer

```
author= serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), write_only=True)
```

therefore, you don't need to override the function `get_serializer_context`. Generally, if you want the authenticated user in the serializer you use `self.context["request"].user`. if you didn't override and change the context in the view class, it will work.

So now about your problem. The query in the functions `get_object` and `get_queryset` in the view class are the same. The function `get_object` should return zero or one instance no more. In the query that you wrote, it may return zero, one, or more than one instance. Another issue that may cause the problem is that I think number 13 in your URL `submission/13` refers to the submission's id but you didn't use it in your query in the function `get_object`.

A hint that I can give it to you is that you can pass the author in `startSubmissionSerializer` when you are debugging the code and after that remove it from the list.